# Mail command misbehave

Tags: linux, shell

I have written shell script to set user's quota automatically. I have quota.csv from where I used to pick up username and send them first mail and then set quota for that user.
When I executed that script the mail has gone to all users of our domain which should not be happened. The mail should go to only users available inside the quota.csv

Below is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -vx

DIR=/home/opr/administration/quotaset/
LOGFILE=setquota.log

DATA="Dear User,
\n \n \t Your account has been successfully created at Mailhost please take note of the following.
\n \n \t There is a phishing attempt (An email with the subject 'Tata Institute of
Fundamental Research Internet User' has been circulating.) to collect your
id and password of mailhost. This is not legitimate. Please do not disclose
it in any form to anybody even to Computer Centre staff.

If you are in doubt please call Computer Centre staff at 2121

\n \n -Raghavan"

EMAIL=@tifr.res.in

QuotaFILE=quota.csv

cd $DIR

QuotaFILE=`ls -1 quota.csv`

if [ -f "$QuotaFILE"  ]
then
    echo "Script started on `date`" >> $DIR/$LOGFILE

    while read line
    do
        echo -e $DATA | mail -s "Welcome to TIFR Mailhost" -c "msagar@tifr.res.in" "$line$EMAIL"
        edquota -p proto $line
    done < $QuotaFILE

    echo "Script Ended On `date`" >> $DIR/$LOGFILE
else
    exit 
fi
```

What happened if mail command did not find username, will it send mail to all users of the domain?

if you need more details I can give you as I think this seems to be either bug in my script or in mail command.

Please reply

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To help further, you will need to post the first few lines of `quota.csv`.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: my question is only how mail command works if I give command  like below

mail -s "TEST MAIL" "@mydomain.com"

Comment: Then I missed the point of your question.  You should check the documentation for `mail`. Generally, that would simply be an error as there is no `user` for the mailhost to check against in determining whether to accept it. `@domain` is simply an invalid e-mail address. What mail program are you using? `mail`? `mailx`, `heirloom-mail`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

One issue is how you are attempting to assign `DATA`. A **heredoc** can make things more readable and prevent formatting issues with multiline strings.

```
DATA=$(cat<< EOF
Dear User,

    Your account has been successfully created at Mailhost please take note 
of the following.

    There is a phishing attempt (An email with the subject 'Tata Institute of
Fundamental Research Internet User' has been circulating.) to collect your
id and password of mailhost. This is not legitimate. Please do not disclose
it in any form to anybody even to Computer Centre staff.

If you are in doubt please call Computer Centre staff at 2121

-Raghavan
EOF)
```

Next:

```
QuotaFILE=`ls -1 quota.csv`
```

Should simply be:

```
QuotaFILE=quota.csv
```

Not knowing what is in `quota.csv` you should also protect against interpretation of escape sequences with:

```
while read -r line
```

You should also protect the following with braces:

```
"$line$EMAIL"
```

Change to:

```
"${line}${EMAIL}"
```

Lastly, and more importantly, unless your `mail` program has a special feature allowing `@domain` to represent sending mail to all users of the system, your attempt to mail to `@domain` will fail because `@domain` is not a valid e-mail address, the smtp host will likely have no way of determining whether services should be allowed and a whole host of other mail RFC violations.

Give the corrections a try, and verify whether you have something that allows sending to `@domain`, if not, that's your issue.

Comment: If you are going to downvote, at least have the integrity to explain why? Don't simply hide behind an anonymous downvote.

Comment: Because the question is off-topic. I don't like that off-topic questions are answered. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions To change that, I follow some advice from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late Why do you bother the downvote so much? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253227/how-can-we-discourage-over-downvoting-on-questions/253230#253230

Comment: You are in for a rude awakening. A simple, "I think you misread the question" goes a lot further. But many of the 'wet-behind-the-ears' users of SO seem to have to make themselves feel more important by downvoting. Sad...